# Return 2 unique answers per ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that pulls in too much information for what I need. My current query looks like this:

```
USE LetterGeneration 

SELECT g.LetterGenerationTemplateRequestId,
      cast(H.CreatedDate as time) as Time, 
      s.StatusKey 

FROM LetterGenerationStatusHistory H

INNER JOIN LetterGenerationStatus S
ON H.LetterGenerationStatusId = s.LetterGenerationStatusId 
INNER JOIN LetterGeneration G
ON g.LetterGenerationId = h.LetterGenerationId

WHERE g.LetterGenerationTemplateRequestId IN (SELECT [LetterGenerationTemplateRequestId]
                                        FROM [LetterGenerationTemplateRequest]
                                        WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(day,-90, GETDATE()))
AND (s.StatusKey = 'QC1'
OR s.StatusKey = 'Ready')


ORDER BY LetterGenerationTemplateRequestId, h.CreatedDate ASC
```

The results I get look like this:

```
LetterGenerationTemplateRequestId   Time          StatusKey
1732189                          01:14:24.1700000   QC1
1732189                          10:13:25.4730000   READY
1732190                          01:14:26.6600000   QC1
1732190                          01:14:26.7230000   QC1
1732190                          01:14:26.7970000   QC1
1732190                          01:14:26.8770000   QC1
1732190                          01:14:26.9500000   QC1
1732190                          01:14:27.0370000   QC1
1732190                          01:14:27.1100000   QC1
1732190                          04:29:17.7170000   READY
1732190                          04:29:33.8500000   READY
1732190                          04:29:50.7900000   READY
```

What I want is to see only 1 result for each Request ID that is status QC1 and status READY. So ideally it'd look like this:

```
Request ID  Time    Status
1732189 1:14:24 AM  QC1
1732189 10:13:25 AM READY
1732190 1:14:27 AM  QC1
1732190 4:29:18 AM  READY
1732191 1:14:30 AM  QC1
1732191 4:39:28 AM  READY
```

etc

How can I limit the results to only show 1 status result per ID? I've checked some other questions on here and have tried to adjust them to fit my query but my limited knowledge of SQL has made it very difficult.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which database are you using (please tag your question with it). Which time is "the" time to display for each id/status?

Comment: The database name is LetterGeneration and I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT g.LetterGenerationTemplateRequestId,
             cast(H.CreatedDate as time) as Time, 
             s.StatusKey,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g.LetterGenerationTemplateRequestId, s.StatusKey
                                ORDER BY H.CreatedDate DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM LetterGenerationStatusHistory H INNER JOIN
           LetterGenerationStatus S
           ON H.LetterGenerationStatusId = s.LetterGenerationStatusId INNER JOIN
           LetterGeneration G
           ON g.LetterGenerationId = h.LetterGenerationId
      WHERE g.LetterGenerationTemplateRequestId IN (SELECT [LetterGenerationTemplateRequestId]
                                                    FROM [LetterGenerationTemplateRequest]
                                                    WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(day,-90, GETDATE())

                                            ) AND
            s.StatusKey IN ('QC1', 'Ready')
       ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 1
ORDER BY LetterGenerationTemplateRequestId, CreatedDate ASC;
```

The `ORDER BY` in the `ROW_NUMBER()` syntax specifies *which* row you want.  In this case, it is the most recent row.

You can change the "1" in the outer `WHERE` to get as many rows per group as you like.

Comment: When trying this, I get an error with the single "t" located just above the last WHERE clause

Comment: I fixed the "t" issue (missing a close parenthesis) and I am getting some results, but it's only the READY status, not the QC1 status too

Comment: @D.Morley . . . A misunderstanding of the question.  Just add the status to the `partition by`.